# Accessing SQLite3 database in HTML / PHP file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sqlite

I have a index.html file, and a populated SQLite3 database called newdb.db, with one table 'NUMBERS' and the fields 'ID', 'NAME' and 'AVG'. This database is stored locally in same folder as the html file.

I simply want to get data from this table and use it within a  in my HTML file to use.

I have attempted a couple examples from online but none seem to work.

Fine with creating a PHP file or something if needed.

Comment: use a .php file and your webserver should have a php extension installed

Comment: Am fine with using a php file if that's what will get the job done. Would you be able to point me in the right direction of how to implement that?

Answer (score 0):

while you trying to get data from database with an .html file without Server Client side i meant PHP or etc that's are imposibble thing to do. But maybe you can do that with node.js.

Comment: Why not use index.php?

Comment: Well maybe you can use node.js for showing data from database.

Comment: Normally you would do this Server Side / PHP / Node etc, but it's actually possible to do this client side -> https://github.com/kripken/sql.js

Comment: I'm also not sure if I do this with the .html file. But maybe this can be done with node.js

Comment: Node.js is completely out of scope here, he does not use it, he did not mention it

Comment: I would be fine with creating an index.php if that would help. Currently just have some javascript in my html file that creates a bar chart, and just want the chart to use the SQLite data rather than just an array in the javascript code. Would be fine with moving it all into a PHP file if that would help me.

Comment: hmm sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
try {
    $sqlite = new PDO("sqlite:newdb.db");
    $sqlite->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die($e);
}
    $sth = $sqlite->prepare('SELECT *
        FROM NUMBERS');
    $sth->execute();
    $result = $sth->fetchAll();
?>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>AVG</th>
  </tr>
<?php
    foreach($result as $row)
        print '<tr><td>'.$row['ID'].'</td><td>'.$row['NAME'].'</td><td>'.$row['AVG'].'</td></tr>';
?>
</table>
```

Comment: (Incoming stupid question): Where do I put this? Putting it in the HTML file just results in some bits of the code getting simply printed onto the webpage, and can see it's not being recognised as code in the text editor in the terminal.

Comment: I put it in index.php, which is the file that is being used for the webpage. I pasted the code into the file and it simply writes out the code text onto the webpage, starting from "setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); ..." . It leaves out some code, but that code is just being printed out onto the page. Have been having this issue with other php code I have been trying.

Comment: Fixed it by reinstalling php, strange. However now have error: 'PDOException: could not find driver in /var/www/html/index.php:16 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/index.php(16): PDO->__construct('sqlite:newdb.db') #1 {main}'

Comment: Found the driver and working perfectly thanks! What format is $results in now then? Not sure how to use the data within $results to form an array of the numbers it gets.